# What are the parameters for AWS Media Amazon image hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url

I'm working with an API which uses Amazon to host images. The image URLs look like this:

```
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZmExNmEwYWItYmQzOS00YjA5LTk2MjktZjEyZDE1Y2QxNjA1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTI4NTNhZDMtMWNkZi00MTRmLWJmZDQtMmJkMGVmZTEzODlhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjc1NTYyMjg@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg
...
```

The schema of the URL is something like this:

```yaml
https://{{HOSTER}}/images/M/{{IMAGE_ID}}@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg
```

I was wondering what settings are the stuff behind the @ symbol? `@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg` Is there anywhere a documentation what parameters do what? Compression, width, height?

Comment: That URL is not part of Amazon Web Services (AWS) or Amazon S3. It seems to be serving content for [Amazon Stores](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/AmazonStores/Help/en/index.html) amongst other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

okay so i've been wondering this too, and since i couldn't find any documentation online, i just tried all parameters i could find and wrote down these docs.

*(disclaimer: i don't guaranteee they are 100% accurate and i'm not missing some parameters)*

## imdb image / amazon image api reference

> this is the imdb image api ref i cobbled together by trial, error, blood, sweat & tears

### syntax:

- starts with `@@._V1_` or `@._V1_` (i assume api version)
- then parameters as 2 uppercase letters of parameter name, and value, e.g `QL100`, separated by `_`
- a the end there is a `,width,height` and `.jpg` or whatever format
- full image can be: `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/<whatever>@._V1_QL75_UY562_CR1,0,380,562.jpg`
- *technically* all of the params are optional and you can just get raw image with `@._V1_.jpg`.

### parameters

- **QL** (optional) is quality 1-100. this applies slight compression. recommended param, otherwise you can get like 80mb image
- **UY** should match the height, otherwise will have white borders
- **UX** (optional) should match the width, otherwise will have white borders
- **CR** is crop:

  - `CR0,0,` or `CR0,,` is no crop. good for larger/hq images
  - `CR1,0,` is for landscape "contain" style crop
  - `CR1,1,` universal crop for unknown wether landscape or portrait
- **SX** and **SY** (optional) are scaleX and scaleY. basically forces the img to be smaller. wouldn't go lower than SX40
- **AL** adding `_AL_` at the end, before `.jpg` is a valid parameter, but from my testing it doesen't do anything

### examples

- generic example:
  `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZmUzMThjOTItZGY4ZS00ODcwLTliNTMtYjVkM2JmY2QxNmRhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzgxODM4NjM@._V1_QL75_UY562_CR1,0,380,562.jpg`
- ultra low quality example:
  `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MDk1ODExN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIyNjg3MDE@._V1_QL10_UY281_SX100_CR0,,190,281.jpg`
- low quality example:
  `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MDk1ODExN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIyNjg3MDE@._V1_QL75_UY422_CR1,1,285,422.jpg`
- high-ish quality example:
  `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MDk1ODExN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIyNjg3MDE@._V1_QL100_UY1000_CR0,,1500,1000.jpg`
- original image (full quality) example:
  `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MDk1ODExN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIyNjg3MDE@._V1_.jpg`

Comment: Thank you for all your work :) When I find out more I'll comment below maybe we can build a small documentation of it :)

Comment: I believe `CR` requires 4 numbers: `x`, `y`, `w`, `h`, This also mean, that `a the end there is a ,width,height` is actually belong to the `CR` function and not stand-alone width/height. Also full image is when no `CR` `UX` `UY` `SX` or `SY` used, in fact removing everything after `@` (including .jpg) would get full image.

Comment: It is worth noticing that `ImageID` is a base64-encoded string: `MV5BMTg4MDk1ODExN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzIyNjg3MDE` -> `1^A1880958117^A2^Ajpg^Ame8072268701`